# compare to text selections in gedit

Tags: text, tabs, compare, gedit

I'm using gedit. I have multiple tabs open, some are simply text that I have copied from other tabs, and haven't been saved to any file.

Is there a way to compare text that is selected in one tab to text selected in another tab? I know that I can use meld, diffuse, diff, etc., but those  (afaik) require the selections to be saved to files first.

I remember using an editor (maybe emacs?) many years ago that could do something similar. But now I almost exclusively use gedit for text file editing.

Any ideas anyone?

TIA

ken

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got a pointer from google:

In gedit, I created a new external tool that will run *diff* with the clipboard contents against the currently selected text.

Here's the bash code for the tool:

```
#!/bin/bash

SEL=$(cat)
diff -B <(echo -en "$SEL") <(xclip -selection c -o)
```

Note that this requires *xclip*, which is in most linux's repos. Sorry, don't know about Windoze.